# How to create 2 plots side by side when there are two categories in your dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
d = {'label': ['true', 'false', 'true', 'false', 'false'],
     'count': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
     'date': [2019-01-01, 2019-01-02, 2019-01-03, 2019-01-04, 2019-01-05]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I am trying to create a cumulative sum using `count` for each `label` and plot them side by side.
However, I've only been able to do so in the following way:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values="count", index=["date"], columns=["label"], aggfunc=np.sum)
pivot = pivot.cumsum()

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20,7]
plt.plot(pivot)
plt.ylabel('Cumulative number')
plt.xlabel('Time')
```

It works fine, except both categories are in a single plot. I'd like to create them side by side with **y-label** as something like 10^0, 10^1, 10^2 and so on, something like this:

[image]

Any guidance please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.relplot(data=pivot.melt(ignore_index=False), x='date', y='value', col='label', kind='scatter')
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. Could you please tell me how can I get 10^0, 10^1 .... on y-axis?

Comment: Okay, thank you :)